# Pass object to prototype callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the [Nivo Slider plugin](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/) for jQuery. The plugin allows you to provide some callbacks in an `object` inside the parameters of the plugin's prototype e.g.

```
$('.slider').nivoSlider({
    afterLoad: control_responses(this, false),
    beforeChange: control_responses(this, false),
    afterChange: control_responses(this, false)
});
```

Where I have passed `this` to `control_responses()` I actually want to send the current iteration of `$('.slider')` however `this` currently refers to the `window object`.

How would I pass the current iteration of `$('.slider')` to my callback functions?

Comment: Can you post the definition of `control_reponses`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the `control_responses` function and putting the return values in the object. Put functions in the object so that the `control_responses` function will be called when the callback function is called:

```
$('.slider').nivoSlider({
  afterLoad: function() { control_responses(this, false); },
  beforeChange: function() { control_responses(this, false); },
  afterChange: function() { control_responses(this, false); }
});
```

Comment: +1. `.bind()` should be an alternative aswell, if he's got a node reference cached.